# Vue JS if/else statment inside computed property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm trying to do an if / else statement inside a computed property for Vue JS for a search, this is what I've got and it's not working, how could I adapt this to work?

```
computed: {
    filteredProperties: function(){
      return this.properties.filter((property) => {
        return property.address.match(this.searchAddress) &&

        if (this.searchType.length > 1) {
          this.searchType.some(function(val){
            return property.type.match(val)
          }) &&
        } else {
          property.type.match(this.searchType) &&
        }

        property.bedrooms.match(this.searchBedrooms) &&
        property.county.match(this.searchCounty)
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: `it's not working` in which way is it not working?

Comment: `render function or template not defined in component: anonymous` it's giving me an error, if I take the if/else statement away and have either one of the two functions then it works.

Comment: Using the `&&` like you're using is invalid... `&& if (condition) {} &&` is invalid. `}) &&
        } else {` - definitely not valid.

Comment: @tymeJV How would I make it valid?

Comment: You could use a ternary, or you could assign the results of the `if` logic to a variable, then just check the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong, can't use an if statement in the middle of an expression. This would work:

```
computed: {
  filteredProperties: function(){
    return this.properties.filter((property) => {

    let searchTypeMatch = this.searchType.length > 1
      ? this.searchType.some(function(val){
        return property.type.match(val)
      })
      : property.type.match(this.searchType)

    return property.address.match(this.searchAddress) &&
      searchTypeMatch &&
      property.bedrooms.match(this.searchBedrooms) &&
      property.county.match(this.searchCounty)
    });
  }
}
```